# How to avoid UIAlertView duplicate show from Notfications

Tags: uialertview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a selector to show `UIAlertView` asking user if want to retry upload images after NotificationCenter post a notification with observename.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNOTIFICATION_PHOTOS_UPLOAD_RETRY object:nil];
```

But because of the notification received more than one, so will show as many as notifications received. Is there a best practice to show alert view only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can do something like:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    UIAlertView *_myAlertView;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass
...
- (void)myNotificationSelector:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (!_myAlertView) {
        _myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init ...]
        _myAlertView.delegate = self;
        [_myAlertView show];
    }
}
...
@end
```

and in the UIAlertViewDelegate handlers, just release and set _myAlertView to NO.

Comment: Thanks! But I found out that I addObserver to the same name `kNOTIFICATION_PHOTOS_UPLOAD_RETRY` in the parent, and alloc/init too many extend classes, cause too many UIViewController display the UIAlertView. So I use your advise and make sure only addObserver to one class.